# BluetoothGatt disconnects after readCharacteristic on ASUS device

Tags: android, bluetooth, disconnect

After connect **connectGatt** and **readCharacteristic** BluetoothGatt disconnects and **onConnectionStateChange** calls on ASUS device. On sony xperia z2 disconnect doesn't happen. I spent a lot of time ... Does anyone have any ideas ?

connect

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            mBluetoothGatt = mDevice.connectGatt(ActivityExamination.this, true, mCallback2 , BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE);
                        } else {
                            mBluetoothGatt = mDevice.connectGatt(ActivityExamination.this, true, mCallback2 );
                        }
```

and listener

```
BluetoothGattCallback mCallback2 = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            Log.e("onConnectionStateChange", "STATUS: " + status + " STATE: " + newState);
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    //status is 8
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    Log.i("gattCallback", "reconnecting...");
                    gatt.connect();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            Log.e("onServicesDiscovered", "STATUS: " + status);
            BluetoothGattService mainService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SERVICE_MAIN);
            BluetoothGattService deviceInfoService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID_SERVICE_DEVICE_INFO);
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic mainCharacteristic = mainService.getCharacteristic(UUID_MAIN_DATA);
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic modelCharacteristic = deviceInfoService.getCharacteristic(UUID_DEVICE_MODEL);
            mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(modelCharacteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            Log.e("onCharacteristicRead", "STATUS: " + status + " CHAR: " + characteristic.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            Log.e("onCharacteristicChanged", "DESCRIPTOR: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);
            Log.e("onDescriptorWrite", "DESCRIPTOR: " + descriptor.toString());
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please provide relevant code on how you are communicating with the devices.

Comment: Done, add code...

Comment: What's the status code of the onConnectionStateChange callback when it disconnects?

Comment: Status code is 8

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues in the past, and most of the time it was related to doing to much work in the actual callback method, which is generally called on a Binder thread if I'm remembering correctly.

Have you tried following a pattern similar to the Android [tutorials](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)?  When receiving events from the bluetooth stack, they send broadcast events to notify of updates.  This changes the thread context to the main thread, which would negate any potential of blocking the binder thread -- which may solve your issue.

Generally I set up a Service to handle my Bluetooth LE communication, and create 2 [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)s, one of the main thread and one a background thread.  The background thread handler is used for parsing events, and the other for initiating communication with the remote BLE device i.e. connection calls, write, read, etc.  This helps take the guess work out of which thread you're calling what on.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: refactor with handlers - same result.

Comment: Is it a status code of 8 every time?  Also, have you tried adding a slight delay before posting the read?  like 250 ms?